# several Compile Errors when using GCC

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to upload a solution to an OJ ,the judge uses GCC
I have received the following errors and having no idea about them.

```
error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
void insert(int in){
^

In function ‘main’:
error: ‘struct mymultiset_int’ has no member named ‘insert’
x.insert(t);
^

error: ‘struct mymultiset_int’ has no member named ‘getmax’
printf("%d\n",x.getmax());
^
error: ‘struct mymultiset_int’ has no member named ‘_delete’
x._delete(0);
^
```

My code looks like this:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int t;
#define swap(a,b) t=b,b=a,a=t
/*
when using swap, I use format like swap(x,y); or swap(x,y),
*/

struct mymultiset_int{
    int e[100000],end;
    void insert(int in){...}
    int getmax(){ return e[0]; }
    void _delete(int i){...}
}x;
int main(){
    x.end=0;memset(x.e,0,sizeof(x.e));
    int N,t;scanf("%d",&N);
    char i[2];
    while (N--){
        scanf("%s",i);
        if (i[0]=='A'){
            scanf("%d",&t);
            x.insert(t);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d\n",x.getmax());
            x._delete(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use functions in a `struct` in C

Comment: #define swap(a,b) t=b,b=a,a=t should be swap(a,b) t=b;b=a;a=t;

Comment: Is C not C++. Struct is not like a Class...

Comment: @Brian, not necessarily.  The given macro definition is a valid C expression.  It would be safer to put it in parentheses, though: `(t=b,b=a,a=t)`.

Comment: Ah ok, I figured the compiler was expecting semicolons and not comas. Is there any difference in this scenario?

Comment: @Brian yes, there is a difference.  Using the comma operator it's all one expression (whose type and value are those of the sub-expression following the last comma).  You can use it anywhere you can use a value.  With semicolons it's three separate statements.

Comment: Moral of this story: do not use a C++ compiler as your reference compiler for C development.  C++ and C are different languages.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I mainly use C++ and I didn't notice that this function isn't available in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot define function in structure in C.

But it is possible in c++.